# how to debug oh-my-zsh auto-completion not working?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

The title largely says it. Most of my auto-completion is working, but `git` is not. It does not complete commands, e.g. `git check<tab>`, nor does it complete branches, e.g. `git checkout ge<tab>`.

It used to until at most a few weeks ago (no idea what changed).

Other completions, such as filenames and directories and commands, work fine.

macOS, git installed via homebrew, zsh with oh-my-zsh, lots of common (i.e. bash and zsh) commands in `~/.common_profile`, which is sourced by both `~/.zshrc` and `~/.bashrc`. It is not that disabling it, as I tried commenting it out. I have both `git` and `gitfast` plugins enabled.

The `git` plugin aliases seem to be working fine. I can run `^X?` to get a dump, but no idea how to interpret the dump.

UPDATE 1: I switched from the default macOS zsh (5.8) to the one installed via homebrew (5.9) and now it works. But I still want to understand why it failed.

UPDATE 2: As suggested by Gilles in the comments, I posted the debug output. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/deitch/37a1df8ae93667346f74630ee86c209f).

Comment: How to debug? Well, `^X?` and analyze the dump. If you need help with that, post the dump! As it stands, your question contains its own answer.

Comment: Ha! Good point.

Comment: Updated to include the dump in a gist @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil'